# How to untaint execution of system command

Tags: ruby, exec

I have a script that can be called by untrusted users, we need to make a call along the lines of this made up example:

```
system 'somescript ' + data
```

We need to ensure if `data == 'filename; dosomethingelse'` then the ; is escaped (or any other special character. The result is the shell command run is actually `somescript filename\;\ dosomethingelse` or `somescript "filename; dosomethingelse"`

Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
system 'somescript', data
```

Multi-argument calls to `system` are not passed to the shell for processing.

Comment: On a completely different note, it reminds me of questions where people ask how to escape strings so they're safe for use as an SQL string literal...the correct answer is "don't"; prepared statements are the correct way to go. In the same way, the correct way to make strings safe as program arguments is to not let them near the shell. :-P

Comment: Or how to parse HTML using regexes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

The Shellwords module (part of the standard library) will do the appropriate escaping for shell commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'shellwords'

command = ['cat', 'filename with spaces', '"quoted_filename"'].shelljoin
puts command    # => cat filename\ with\ spaces \"quoted_filename\"
system(command)
# => this file has spaces in its name
# => this file has a quoted filename
```

shellwords also adds a shellescape method to String.

These methods are not in the [online API documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Shellwords.html).  They are partially documented in the 1.9 Pickaxe, and are known to be present in MRI 1.8.7.  The actual file (on my box, in /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/shelljoin.rb) is well commented.